# Import json file into collection in server code on startup

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I've exported a MongodB collection to a JSON file on my local test machine and want to import it through the Meteor.js server side code on startup (after deploying to a meteor.com site). I'm not finding any examples of this yet.

Thanks

Comment: See Assets.getText() at http://docs.meteor.com

Comment: And that alone imports the contents into a collection in MongoDB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example:

```
    // import data only when Products collection is empty

    if (Products.find().count() === 0) {
        console.log("Importing private/products.json to db")

        var data = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("products.json"));

        data.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            Products.insert(item);
        })
    }
```

Comment: man, this really helped me, too.  To anyone else who found their way to this issue: I used this to fix a problem of _ids being formatted as ObjectId("blahblah") after i imported some json from an external file in mongodb and my iron-router routes didn't work.  I just junked that database and imported the json directly using this technique, it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

If your set of products is small, you could have it all in the same file, and remove the parsing.

```
var products = [{/* product 1 */}, {/* product 2 */), ...];

if (Products.find().count() === 0) {
  products.forEach(function (product) {
    Products.insert(product);
  });
}
```

OR

With the new imports in Meteor 1.3, you could import them instead, like so.

```
// fixtures/products.js

export default [{/* product 1 */}, {/* product 2 */), ...];

// fixtures/seed.js

import products from './products.js';

if (Products.find().count() === 0) {
  products.forEach(function (product) {
    Products.insert(product);
  });
}
```